# Atom: How to search in only the current folder?

Tags: atom-editor

I've read the documentation [here](https://atom.io/docs/v0.194.0/using-atom-find-and-replace) and about [Glob pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29), but still couldn't find a way to search the current folder only(not including the subfolders).

That is, if I open "search in project" and type "meta/*.php" into the "fire/directory pattern" field, the search will be against all *.php files in folder "meta" and all of its subfolders. 
So how do I search the "meta" folder only?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using glob with depth unknown subfolders are included in search otherwise it will search in the specified folder only

```
C:\\dir1\dir2\*.ext
```

The above pattern will search only in the files with extension .ext inside the dir2 excluding subfolders

```
C:\\dir1\**\*.ext
```

The double star is called unknown depth and will search in the files with extension .ext inside dir1 including all subfolders